# Using Excel to verify entries

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to automate checking a demographic sheet filled in by a trainee against an answer key.

Our sheet currently has data validation built in to return TRUE or FALSE on whether the answer matches the answer key, but I'm looking for a way to then display the exact text string, so as to provide feedback on the exact error.

For example the way it currently functions is:

Sheet1!A1=Cat

Sheet2!A1=Dog

Sheet3!A1=FALSE

What I'm looking for, is a to utilize VBA to generate a comment balloon on Sheet3!A1 and see the exact error for easier feedback.

I'm new to working with advanced functions in Excel, so if anyone has a pointer in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it!!

Comment: Do you have code that you have tried that we may be able to debug for you, or are you asking us how to start in the first place?

Comment: If anyone has an idea of where to start, or ideas generally on how that can best be accomplished, I would appreciate it. I do not have code yet.

Comment: 1. Iterate over each cell that's been filled in and needs checking, 2. Perform the check (you don't specify what exactly 'matching the answer key' entails, but presume you can basically just use the logic implemented in the data validation applied to those cells), 3. If cell matches its respective answer key, do nothing. If it doesn't, use `Range.AddComment` along with the `answer key` (whatever that is in the context of your question).

Comment: It would probably help the people who will answer your question if you provide some screenshots of your workbook or make some attempt to start the code. It is difficult to help blindly.

Answer (score 1):

I Suppose your want to check Sheet1 = Sheet2 in sheet3, and show the error if does not match.

To make it simple, just use formula in sheet 3,

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1,"",Sheet1!A1 & "|" &Sheet2!A1)
```

if they match, nothing will be show, if they don't match, it will show Sheet1figure|Sheet2figure

this is easier than showing True/False

Comment: this is fantastic thank you osman. ill give it a try